# How to filter array of objects in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, filter, grouping

I want to filter this data array into state and city array. How can I achieve this using lodash or any other better way rather than for loop and maintaining extra arrays.

```
data: [
    { id: 1, name: Mike, city: philps, state: New York},
    { id: 2, name: Steve, city: Square, state: Chicago},
    { id: 3, name: Jhon, city: market, state: New York},
    { id: 4, name: philps, city: booket, state: Texas},
    { id: 5, name: smith, city: brookfield, state: Florida},
    { id: 6, name: Broom, city: old street, state: Florida},
]
```

which user click `state`, list of state appears.

```
{state: New York, count: 2},
{state: Texas, count: 1},
{state: Florida, count: 2},
{state: Chicago, count: 1},
```

When user click particular state, list of `cities` of that state appears. For ex. when user clicks New York state,

```
{id:1, name: Mike, city: philps}
{id:3, name: Jhon, city: market}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a javascript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With lodash, you could use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter) with an object as *[`_.matches`](https://lodash.com/docs/#matches) iteratee shorthand* for filtering the object with a given key/value pair and

use [`_.countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#countBy) with [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) for getting a count of states.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Mike', city: 'philps', state: 'New York' }, { id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago' }, { id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York' }, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas' }, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida' }, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida' }];

console.log(_.filter(data, { state: 'New York' }));
console.log(_
    .chain(data)
    .countBy('state')
    .map((count, state) => ({ state, count }))
    .value()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for states count, its printing out data array as a result.

Comment: The output is exactly correct as showing in sinppet. But i'm not getting the same.

Comment: For the second console.  Getting data as result

Comment: you could add `value()` to get a rendered result without methods of lodash.

Answer (score 51):

You can do this using `native` javascript by applying `filter` method which accepts as *parameter* a `callback` provided function.

```js
let data = [ { id: 1, name: 'Mike', city: 'philps', state:'New York'}, { id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York'}, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'}, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'}, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'}, ]

data = data.filter(function(item){
   return item.state == 'New York';
}).map(function({id, name, city}){
    return {id, name, city};
});
console.log(data);
```

Another approach is to use `arrow` functions.

```js
let data = [ { id: 1, name: 'Mike', city: 'philps', state:'New York'}, { id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'}, { id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York'}, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'}, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'}, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'}, ]

data = data.filter((item) => item.state == 'New York').map(({id, name, city}) => ({id, name, city}));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I have some empty in the array object. How can I remove and need to use the values. Here need to show all except empty. let data = [ { id: , name: '', city: '', state:''},{ id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'},{ id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York'}, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'}, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'}, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'}, ]data = data.filter((item) => item.state == 'New York').map(({id, name, city}) => ({id, name, city}));console.log(data);

Comment: `let data = [ { id: , name: '', city: '', state:''},{ id: 2, name: 'Steve', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'},{ id: 3, name: 'Jhon', city: 'market', state: 'New York'}, { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'}, { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'}, { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'}, ]data = data.filter((item) => item.state == 'New York').map(({id, name, city}) => ({id, name, city}));console.log(data);`

Comment: Yall realized this doesn't work in the emulators or in the actual device? I think the question was constructed for this purpose.

Answer (score 11):

Simply Follow filter function 
For Example

```
return data.filter(data => data.state == "New York" && count === 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly simple using `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.reduce` and destructuring:

```
//filter by particular state
const state = /*the given state*/;
const filtered = data
.filter(e => e.state == state)//filter to only keep elements from the same state
.map(e => {
  const {id, name, city} = e;
  return {id, name, city};
});//only keep the desired data ie id, name and city

//get states array
const states = data
.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  const state_names = acc.map(e => e.state);//get all registered names

  if(state_names.includes(elem.state)){//if it is already there
    const index = acc.find(e => e.state==elem.state);
    acc[index] = {state: acc[index].state, count: acc[index].count+1};//increment it's count
    return acc;
  }else//otherwise
    return [...acc, {state: elem.state, count: 1}];//create it
}, []);
```

cf [this jsfiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.net/Voltra/td8f20ky/1/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this way    
const users = [
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  number: '123-456-7890',
  address: '123 Main Street, City, Country',
},
{
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  number: '987-654-3210',
  address: '456 Oak Avenue, Town, Country',
},
{
  name: 'Alice Johnson',
  number: '555-123-4567',
  address: '789 Elm Road, Village, Country',
},
];

const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState([]);

const handleSearch = text => {
setSearchText(text);
const filteredData = users.filter(user => {
  const searchTextLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();
  return (
    user.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextLowerCase) ||
    user.number.includes(searchText) ||
    user.address.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextLowerCase)
  );
 });

 setFilteredUsers(filteredData);
};

   <TextInput
        placeholder="Search Name Number or Address"
        placeholderTextColor={'#666'}
        style={styles.bottomSheetSearchBar}
        onChangeText={handleSearch}
        value={searchText}
      />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).